# I seem to be facing an error with using the async pipe operator

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 <div class="image" *ngFor="let post of (userData | async)?.posts"></div>
```

The error msg: 
Identifier 'userData' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member.

Comment: give more details about error and component class file too

Comment: We would need you .ts file to read into that but in addition you could start by seperating the pipe from the the rest be switching to a div with *ngIf = "userData | async as user" so that you then should have your sync data in the template

Comment: Is the (userData | async)?.posts question mark there for optional chaining?

Comment: Thanks but I managed to solve the error

Comment: The property I created in my ts file isn't the property I linked to in my html page

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no `userData` in your component class TS file. Can you post your component file?

Answer (score 0):

Can we handle through this code?

```
   <ng-container *ngIf="userData.length > 0">
   <div class="image" *ngFor="let post of (userData | async).posts"></div>
   <ng-container>
```